# How would you describe this condition?

Tags: word-choice

How would you describe the condition under which someone answers questions without letting his mood affect his choice of answering? I want him to answer the questionnaire without mood bias.

Please let me know if the following are viable examples, and how would you describe it:

> 1. Please answer the questions with bias-free mood.
> 2. Please answer the questions with free of mood influence/bias.
> 3. Please answers the questions with a state devoid of mood influence/bias

Answer (score 3):

*Objectively* means bias-free, and *rationally* would be good single word that means emotion- or mood-free, without suggesting that they may have a problem containing their emotions/moods.

> Please answer the questions objectively and rationally.

Answer (score 3):

> Please answer the questions **impartially**.

[***impartial***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/impartial) meaning

> favoring no one side or party more than another; without prejudice or bias; fair; just fair

Comment: Can you give more of an explanation?

Comment: This is a good one - "impartial" is used to describe how e.g. jurors should behave at a trial ("impartial jury") meaning only consider the facts of the evidence and testimony.

Answer (score 2):

> Please answer the questions **dispassionately**.

From the adjective *dispassionate*, which directly refers to mood:

> Not influenced by strong emotion,
>   and so able to be rational and impartial: 
>   ‘she dealt with life’s disasters in a calm, dispassionate way’
>   
>   [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dispassionate#dispassionate)